# How can I persist NSPredicateEditor NSPredicateEditorRowTemplates data

Tags: swift, xcode, nspredicateeditor

I've been struggling with getting the information entered in an `NSPredicatEditor` from session to session in a `Swift` project.

Any guidance or samples would be greatly appreciated.

What I've got so far.

1. A predicate editor that is functional implemented in an Action Sheet.
2. Bound predicate to an NSArrayController also bound to a CoreData Table.
3. A method to generate Row Templates based on CoreData Table Attributes.

What is not working.

- A bound predict variable to the `predicateditor`  getting error on not
  being able to match the predicate to a row template also at the
  `awakefromnib` seems to be where this is checked the row templates are
  not initialised (nil )at this point from the InterfaceBuilder

What I want to be able to do
Using the `NSUSerDefaults` persist the contents of the predicate editor so that when the application is re-started this editor has the data last entered.

Comment: Edit the question, formatting and highlight key point.

Answer (score 0):

Load the previously saved predicate by setting the editor's `objectValue` property.

```
predicateEditor.objectValue = predicate
```

> After setting up the predicate editor, you typically send it a `objectValue` message to restore a saved predicate. [source](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nspredicateeditorrowtemplate#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004605-CH1-DontLinkElementID_1)

It sounds like you may have a complicated setup involving Interface Builder, array controllers, Core Data, bindings, etc. Try it through code instead: load the row templates, then load the predicate.